# Protecting sensitive postgres data from privileged users

Tags: postgresql, security

Is there a way in postgres or using some other tool to allow for a privileged user (admin) to have necessary privileges for administrative functions but not be able to actually query sensitive data?

Comment: What exactly do you consider an "administrative function"?

Comment: Anything a DBA would do - start/stop, create indexes, etc

Comment: Then no. A DBA (who presumable also sets up the database in the first place?) needs access to a role that owns the objects, so he will always be able to view all rows if he wanted to. You will need to trust your DBA(s), there are only administrative (corporate) measures not technical ones. E.g. don't grant anyone access to the production database, only allow them to commit scripts that will be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

The only means you have is encryption. And not on the DB side, but on the application side before the data is stored in the database.

This is the same issue as you using some cloud storage. How do you prevent e.g. Google from spying on your data you put into Google Drive?